# Can somebody explain me how to make my JSON inside of : let parameters: [String: AnyObject]?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I need to send this JSON with HTTP post request, but I Want to convert him to a String, I have problem with the " " 
if somebody can do it for me or explain it for me it will help me,
thank you!

```
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "data": {
        "image": {
          "url": "https://someImage.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this JSON(with the " ") to one line String?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let str :[String:Any] =  [
    "inputs": [
    [
    "data": [
    "image": [
    "url": "https://someImage.jpg"
    ]
    ]
    ]
]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this JSON(with the " ") to one line String?

Answer (score 0):

To make it dynamic use following approach:

```
let url = [
    "url": "https://someImage.jpg"
]

let data = [
    "image":url
]

let inputs = [
    "data": [data]
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this JSON(with the " ") to one line String?

Comment: You can either keep value as "" or you can remove key and value pair from JSON.